# Markdown: hyperlink back to the TOC

Tags: markdown

Is there a way to add a link to get back to the TOC?

I often use Typora to edit my markdown. Occasionally I export the doc I am working on to a PDF. This is a convenient tool because the PDF supports all the linking throughout the doc. So, the TOC provides a great way to jump to content.

What if I wanted a link back to the TOC underneath some headings? Lets say I have a 50 page PDF that  I generated from markdown (or a very vertically long rendered markdown doc), it would be awfully convenient if a user of the PDF/doc could jump to content on page 45(75% the way down or so), then jump back to the TOC with only 2 clicks, and no scrolling. One click from the TOC to the content, then one click of a link in the content that says "back to TOC" or something similar.

It is as if I want this markdown to automagically work:

```
[link to TOC](this.TOC)
```

or

```
[link to TOC](#TOC#)
```

Comment: ```
I guess I could just link to a heading very close to the TOC, or add a heading to the TOC and link to that :/

so, one click at the TOC to get to content, then a link somewhere to the heading ### Table of contents which just so happens to be above the TOC.  

dumb question maybe.